# Function won't allow undefined parameter

Tags: javascript, csv, callback

I'm trying to source a function that takes in an array "XY".  JS throws an error saying that I can't index the variable.  But this seems crazy since it's just loading a function - of course the array isn't defined yet!  What am I missing?

```
function reformat(XY) {
    "use strict";

var exper = [];
    exper.X = [];
    exper.Y = [];

    for(var i=0;i<XY.length;i++){ // here, throws error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined "
        exper.X[i] = XY[i][0];
        exper.Y[i] = XY[i][1];
    }

}; // END reformat
```

Function is used as a callback after data is loaded:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        loadXY("XY.csv", reformat);
    </script>


function loadXY(fname,callback){
    d3.csv(fname, function(data) {
        var XY = data.map(function(d) { return [ Number(d["X"]), Number(d["Y"])]; });
    });
    callback(XY);
}
```

EDIT: adding html context in case that helps:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Experiment</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="easeljs-min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="numeric-min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="jquery-min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="jquery.csv-0.71.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

    <script src="d3.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="reformat.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="loadXY.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

    <link rel=stylesheet href="task.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        loadXY("XY.csv", reformat);
    </script>

    <canvas id="easel" width="640" height="480"> Stop Using IE! </canvas>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing XY inside of the previous loop. you need to move `callback(XY);` into the function above it like so:

```
function loadXY(fname,callback){
    d3.csv(fname, function(data) {
        var XY = data.map(function(d) { return [ Number(d["X"]), Number(d["Y"])]; });
        callback(XY);
    });

}
```

Comment: We have a winner!  You just ended soo many hours of frustration - thanks so much.  In general, why can't the callback work so long as it's inside the function taking the callback as a parameter?

Comment: The callback was working. The problem was that XY was not inside it's scope when it was provided XY as an argument. Moving it into the same block as XY allowed it to "see" XY and use it. If you had simply tried to do `XY.toString()`, it would have given the same error.